# sqlite extract two row from two tables to create a new table

Tags: sqlite, transpose, multiple-tables

I have an sqlite db with two table

**table1**

```
------------------------------
TIME | ElevationA| ElevationB|
-----|-----------|-----------|
T1   |   eA1     |  eB1      |
T2   |   eA2     |  eB2      |
```

**table2**

```
------------------------------
TIME | Temperat A| Temperat B|
-----|-----------|-----------|
T1   |   tA1     |  tB1      |
T2   |   tA2     |  tB2      |
```

I am searching for a "*magic*" command that make a table of all parameter at a given time, e.g something that would be like:

```
SELECT WHERE TIME=T1 table1 AS ELEV ,table2 AS TEMP
```

and that would result in

**table3**

```
------------
ELEV | TEMP |
-----|----- |
eA1  | tA1  |
eB1  | tB1  |
```

Of course I could bash script it but I would prefer a to create a view in SQLite as it is more straightforwards and avoid to duplicate the data.
Any idea welcome

Comment: How would you give `T1` to the view? Do you want a view with all times?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE3(ELEV,TEMP);
INSERT INTO TABLE3(ELEV,TEMP) VALUES((SELECT TIME FROM TABLE1 WHERE TIME = T1),SELECT TIME FROM TABLE2 WHERE TIME =T2));
```

These 2 select clauses must return the same number of records.

Comment: No
If you do that you get
`
----------
ELEV|TEMP|
 T1 | T2 |
----------`

Comment: Can't format the table right on this website... anyway, it is not what I seek for